# getting same result in every loop with urllib and bs4 from an address although site has different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

while True:
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/markets/"

    response = request.urlopen(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
  
    result = (soup.body.div.div.find("div", {"class":"container cmc-main-section"})
        .find("div", {"class":"cmc-main-section__content"}).div.div.div
        .find("div", {"class":"f6l7tu-0 jGlJVl cmc-details-panel-price"}).span.span)
    b=[]
    b = list(filter(None, result))
    print(b[0])

time.sleep(10)
```

this is my code
whenever I run the program there is no Error but each time it prints the same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first: It is a bit aggressiv ;) you should indent your `time.sleep(10)` in the loop.

**What is going on?**

In the moment you are requesting the website, you get an initial content back, that also includes a "chached" value of the `price`.

A moment later website updates contents dynamically, so you have to wait for that update.

**What you can do is go with selenium:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/markets/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
while True:
    driver.get(url)
    #driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
    sleep(10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

    result = soup.find("div", {"class":"f6l7tu-0 jGlJVl cmc-details-panel-price"}).span.span.text
    print(result)

driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
$25.391,31
$25.396,88
$25.392,99
$25.381,44
$25.373,13
$25.373,13
$25.359,99
$25.359,99
$25.355,07
$25.327,24
$25.330,22
$25.375,47
$25.341,14
$25.390,14
$25.345,10
```

Comment: I didnt use selenium yet. Could you explain webdriver address you wrote and how to get it?!

Comment: Selenium requires a driver to interface with the chosen browser. Firefox, for example, requires geckodriver, which needs to be installed before --- [Docs of selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers)

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks!

Comment: Instead using selenium you also can wait for a longer period of time and run again, cause the initial "cached value" is changing after a few minutes, but thing, that is not as cool as the selenium solution.